# SQLModel: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected,

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymysql, sqlmodel

I am using the SQLModel library to do a simple `select()` like described on their official website. However I am getting `Column expression or FROM clause expected` error message

```
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Field, Session, SQLModel, create_engine, select

from models import Hero
    
sqrl = f"mysql+pymysql:///roo@asdf:localhost:3306/datab"

engine = create_engine(sqrl, echo=True)


def create_db_and_tables():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


def select_heroes():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(Hero)
        results = session.exec(statement)
        for hero in results:
            print(hero)


def main():
    select_heroes()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

this is my `models/Hero.py` code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
    created: datetime
    lastseen: time
```

when I run app.py I get the `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <module 'models.Hero' from '/Users/dev/test/models/Hero.py'>.` message

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message `<Column expression or FROM clause expected, got module 'models.Hero' from '/Users/dev/test/models/Hero.py'>` tells us:

- SQLAlchemy / SQLModel *expected* to receive a Column expression or FROM clause: in the ORM layer this often means a model class or collection of model's columns was expected
- SQLAlchemy / SQLModel *unexpectedly* received a module object named `models.Hero`
- that you have a module named `Hero.py`

The solution is to replace the object causing the error with something that the `select` or `query` function would expect to receive, such as an SQLAlchemy or SQLModel ORM model class.

The import statement `from models import Hero` only imports the *module* `Hero`.  Either

- change the import to import the model<sup>*</sup>

  ```py
  from models.Hero import Hero
  ```
- change the code in `select_heroes` to reference the model<sup>†</sup>

  ```py
  statement = select(Hero.Hero)
  ```

---

* It's [conventional to use all lowercase](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) for module names; following this convention will help you distinguish between modules and models.

† This approach is preferable in my opinion: accessing the object via the module namespace eliminates the possibility of name collisions (of course it can be combined with lowercase module names).

Comment: thank you! is there a way for me to do something like `from models import Hero, Villains`, etc ? for me it seems more cleaner that way if I can just say from `models/` directory, import these classes.

Comment: Yes: expose the names in `models.__init__`: for example `from hero import Hero` and then you can do `from models import Hero`.  You definitely want to avoid your module and class names colliding in such a structure.

Answer (score 2):

I got this because I forgot to inherit Base class in my model.

my model was:

```
class WeatherData:
   __tablename__ = "weather_data"
   ...
```

Then I only change to

```
 Base = declarative_base()

 class WeatherData(Base):
       __tablename__ = "weather_data"
```

sqlalchemy explain this in: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html#declare-models

Answer (score 1):

I got same error with below script

```
            from sqlalchemy.sql import select, text
            from dask.dataframe import read_sql_query

            con = "sqlite:///delete_me_test.sqlite"
            query = "SELECT * FROM ticks"
            query2 = " * FROM ticks"

            def _remove_leading_select_from_query(query):
                if query.startswith("SELECT "):
                    return query.replace("SELECT ", "", 1)
                else:
                    return query


            #sa_query = select(text(_remove_leading_select_from_query(query)))
            sa_query = select(text(_remove_leading_select_from_query(query)))
            print(sa_query)
            ddf = read_sql_query(sql=sa_query, con=con, index_col="index")

            print(ddf)
            print(ddf.head(3))
```

and got it fixed by force downgrade sqlalchemy version

```
pip install --force-reinstall 'sqlalchemy<2.0.0'
```

[ref](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/11880)

Comment: In conda: `conda install -c conda-forge 'sqlalchemy<2.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error after importing the model class twice

```py
from app.models.company import CompanyIndustryType
from uuid import UUID
...
from app.schemas.company import CompanyIndustryType

...

for item in data:
                query = select(CompanyIndustryType).where(
                    CompanyIndustryType.id == item.industry_id)
                results = await db.execute(query)
                item.industry = results.scalars().first()

...
```

so I got the error

```
Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <class 'app.schemas.company.CompanyIndustryType'>.
```

The solution was simply by removing the second import, and everything worked well